# Mongo DB - filter only future dates

Tags: angular, mongodb, timestamp, restheart

I'm making a request from Angular to a MongoDB table (accessed through RESTHeart) where each record contains a "startDate" field. When I fetch some records I get this date as an object:

```
startDate: {$date: 1609718400000}
```

I want to filter only future dates, however this filter query doesn't work as expected:

```
`{ "startDate": { $gt: { $date: ${Date.now()} } } }`
```

I'm still getting past dates. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Here's my angular function:

```
getTerms(url: string): Observable<TermDto[]> {
    const params = createParams()
        .append('filter', `{ "startDate": { $gt: { $date: ${Date.now()} } } }`);
    
    return this.client.get<TermDto[]>(url, {params})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way that worked for me was this:

```
{ startDate: { $gt: new Date() } }
```

My problem derived from using an aggregation - when I passed additional "avars" query parameter:

```
...?avars={'id': "some-id"}&filter={'startDate': {$gt: new Date()}}
```

It somehow ignored the "filter" parameter. It would be great if someone was able explain why it happens.

My final solution for aggregation was validating date on frontend.

Answer (score 1):

RESTHeart uses the [Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#bson.Date) representation of MongoDB.

Dates are represented as `{"$date": {"$numberLong": "<millis>"}}`

Where `< millis >` is the epoch time in milliseconds.

So the correct filter is:

```
?filter={ "startDate": { "$gt": {"$date":  {"$numberLong": "1613381427"} } }
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb use ISO format, try replacing `Date.now()` with `new Date().toISOString()`

Comment: Now I'm getting a 400 error with the following message: `"illegal filter paramenter: { 'startDate': { $gt: 2021-02-12T16:04:14.456Z } }"`

Comment: Wrap it with quotes

Comment: Tried that - there is no error, but past dates are still not filtered. The query looks like this: `"{ startDate: { $gt: "2021-02-12T16:17:10.078Z" } }"`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
{ startDate: { $gt: new Date(Date.now()) } }
```

Comment: Nope, still getting 400: `"illegal filter paramenter: { startDate: { $gt: new Date(Date.now()) } }"`